# Nesting in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nested

I don't know if that title even describes what I want to do, but here goes.

I have some JavaScript, which changes the href of a link, depending on what item is selected in a select box. Here's the code:

```
function setText(text) {
    var selectVal = text;
    var url = $('twitter2').attr("href");
    url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on';
 $('a').attr("href", url);
}
```

The problem is there are multiple links on the page. Would there be a way to specify which link to change the URL of? Sorry for the woeful explanation, here's the accompanying html.

```
<twitter2><a><img src="http://stream.cz.cc/images/twitter.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://stream.cz.cc/images/twitterover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://stream.cz.cc/images/twitter.png'" /></a></twitter2>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your image tag and JQuery select it by the ID.

```
<img id="THISONE" src="http://stream.cz.cc/images/twitter.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://stream.cz.cc/images/twitterover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://stream.cz.cc/images/twitter.png'" /></a>
```

Javascript:

```
function setText(text) {
    var selectVal = text;
    var url = $('twitter2').attr("href");
    url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on';
 $('#THISONE').attr("href", url);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it'd be something simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first of all

`var url = $('twitter2').attr("href")` would give you nothing, as `twitter2` does not have any `href` attribute.

second, you can access your a as:

```
url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on';

    $('twitter2 a').first().attr("href", url).
```

This will change the `href` of the *first* a inside the `<twitter2>` tag